# How to do "du" on all files under a directory in linux?

Tags: linux, du

This is what I tried:

```
[demo@ ~]# ll /usr/local/apache2/logs/|xargs |du -hm -
du: cannot access `-': No such file or directory
```

I want to see the amount of space each file occupies in `m` unit.

How to do it the correct way?

Comment: possible dupplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming `ll` is an alias for `ls -l`, in which case what's wrong with

```
du -hm /usr/local/apache2/logs/*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
du -s /usr/local/apache2/logs/* | sort -rn | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying not to descend into subdirectories?

How about:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 |xargs du -m
```

Pipe to "sort -n" if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not *exactly* what you asked for, but `tree -fis` or `tree -fih` might help you a bit and is a small, compact solution. :)

The first command outputs the recursive directory tree showing also the file size in bytes, the second one is the same but has "human readable" output, showing the size in kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes... whatever it considers appropriate for that file.

Comment: This isn't a bad solution, but note that the `tree` command **is not** universal -- in fact none of the systems I looked at (FreeBSD, Debian, OS X) have it.

Comment: Well, it's universal in a way that it's available for practically all the Linux/BSD systems :)