# AWS /dev/xvda1 directory is full

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Sometimes the command `df -h`  gives `/dev/xvda1` directory full. But not all the time. I have checked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/330532/xvda1-is-100-full-what-is-it-how-to-fix) & [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213856) and tried the solutions mentioned there but that didn't help.

Can someone guide what can be the cause?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Find a folder or files containing much volume of disk
with

> du -hsc *

this command will give you result that which folder is containing much data.

Note:- run this command as a root user.

Comment: That gives only 11 GB total.

Comment: It's possible that a process has opened a large file which has since been deleted. You'll have to kill that process to free up the space.

Comment: You can check this with sudo lsof +L1

Answer (score 3):

If your drive is "randomly" filling up, a common explanation would be that you have some form of logs that are dumping tons of information, and `logrotate` is cleaning them up on a routine basis. To identify everything that `logrotate` would be rotating, look at the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file and the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory.

I usually [refer to this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/) or [this article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-largest-filesdirectories-on-a-linuxunixbsd-filesystem/) when I need to find large files or directories on my file system. You may need to locate large files, or large directories, exclusively. This is because the large volume of data that is being written to your disk may not be in the form of one large file, but thousands of tiny ones.

Find top 20 largest directories on the `/` drive (note, you may need to expand this past the top 20, due to `/var`, `/var/log` and `/var/log/httpd` all being returned if `/var/log/httpd` is very large):

```
sudo du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

Find top 20 largest files on the `/` drive :

```
sudo find / -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -20
```

One other suggestion is to look for where your `/home` is mounted. Does it have its own partition, or is it being served off of the `/` partition? If the latter, then someone or some service could inadvertently be uploading large files to their home directory.

If the above has not solved your issue, can you please elaborate on the scenario when `df -h` reports the drive **IS NOT** full? How full is it when it's not full? Can you draw any correlation to time of day, day of week, current work load, etc. for when the drive reports full vs when it does not report full?

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend `ncdu`, a pretty cool tool that is much more informative than the original `du`. I've been using it for many years.

When you run `ncdu`, the output is sorted by the size; then its repl allows you to navigate the directory tree, and see, which subdirectories of a directory are the largest. Gives you a clearer picture of a problem, compared to `du`.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I think it would be good if you could add some reasons you think this tool would help in this case.

Comment: Daniel, you can just try this tool and see how visual it is; you can navigate directories and find which one gobbles most of space, and then, as I remember, you can even delete the files you don't need.