# What is the equivalent to "sudo apt autoremove" in CentOS?

Tags: centos, apt

I read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/946830/965126) but there's no apt command in CentOS. So, how can I remove unused packages in CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's `yum autoremove` since I used `yum` in CentOS instead. Here's [more detailed info](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/apt-centos).