# Map linux folders by size

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-space-utilization, du

I have AWS linux instance, Currently there are many folders in the instance.
I would like to map all the folders and their size, so i could come back in 1 month and check which folder occupy high amount of storage (maybe the logging folder).

What is the best way to achieve this ?
so i could compare the size of this month and next month more easily.
Thanks.

Comment: what you are meaning by 'map all folders' ?

Comment: I suspect you want something like `du -sc /folders_to_map/ > my_logfile`, but your post is not clear enough. Can you clarify your goal?

Comment: Hey, I want to map all the file structure, to make output file that says: /etc/folder 50 MB, /etc/bin 60 MB. so i could come back in the end of the month and see which folder increased in size.. one of my folders occupy 2 GB every 2 months i need to locate the fat folder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ncdu utility](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu). Record the values. Come back and check again in a month :)

```
ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                         
--- /ppro ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  170.0GiB [##########] /data                                                                                       
  104.6GiB [######    ] /sldata
   54.4GiB [###       ] /isam
   48.8GiB [##        ] /slisam
   27.8GiB [#         ] /hist
   15.4GiB [          ] /prt
   12.1GiB [          ] /jmail
   10.1GiB [          ] /zephyr2
    9.7GiB [          ] /edi    
    7.9GiB [          ] /savdata2
    6.2GiB [          ] /io
```

Answer (score 2):

I saved this answer from another question a while ago: [How can I sort du -h output by size](https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size)

Requires coreutils 7.5 or newer.  The command is simple:

```
du -hs * | sort -h
```

Or to sort in descending order, use:

```
du -hs * | sort -hr
```

The output will list directories in order of size, sorted in human readable format (K, M, G)

To compare sizes over time, redirect the output to a file for storage:

```
du -hs * | sort -hr > /path/to/diskusage.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to make a bash script.
This is part of the script:
I output the information of each mail folder sub folders, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
du -h /etc/* | sort -nr | head -n 20 > /outputdir/data/etc.txt
du -h /usr/* | sort -nr | head -n 20 > /outputdir/data/usr.txt
du -h /var/* | sort -nr | head -n 20 > /outputdir/data/var.txt
```

plus adding

```
du -hs /var/ >> /ilantest/data/general.txt
du -hs /usr/ >> /ilantest/data/general.txt
du -hs /etc/ >> /ilantest/data/general.txt
```

This will give me some information on disk usage for most used folders, including to display to top 20 biggest folders and their changes during the tests.